# How to make a contour in python from csv file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, opencsv

Can some one help me. I want to make a contour plot let's say an example of my data below. I have height data and temperatur data in csv file for 4 day :

```
date 1        date 2        date 3         date 4
height temp  height  temp  height  temp  height  temp
9.3    28.0   8.7     27.6  10.0    26.0   9.5    26.8
9.7    27.3   9.3     26.8  12.8    25.5   10.8   25.9
10.0   26.8   10.8    25.9  13.1    25.3   11.4   25.0
10.6   26.5   12.7    24.4  14.8    24.7   12.9   24.2
12.8   26.0   13.5    23.8  15.2    24.3   13.6   23.4
13.3   25.7   17.8    22.7  16.8    23.7   14.0   22.6
16.8   25.4   18.9    22.4  17.9    23.3   14.7   22.0
17.2   24.6   20.0    21.0  18.6    23.0   15.9   21.3
```

And this is my script tried :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import csv
import glob
import os


path = "C:/Users/SYIFAAZRA/Documents/belajar_wradlib/Skew-T/New/"
os.chdir(path)

filenames = glob.glob("*.csv")

dfs = []
for f in filenames:
    col_names = ['height', 'temp']
    df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=',',skiprows=7, usecols=[11, 21], names=col_names, na_values=['----'])
    df = df.dropna()

    max = df.height.idxmax()
    min = df.height.idxmin()
    df = df.loc[min:max, :]

    dfs.append(df)

df2 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=False, axis=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.linspace(0,100, 50)
y = df['height']
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = df['temp']
plt.show()
```

I want to make a contour plot which x= number of date, y=height data, z=temp data. Can someone suggest to me how to resolve my script above.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it helps to present a way of generating your data, rather than pasting it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

d = {('date1', 'height'): {0: 9.3, 1: 9.7, 2: 10.0, 3: 10.6, 4: 12.8, 5: 13.3, 6: 16.8, 7: 17.2},
     ('date1', 'temp'): {0: 28.0, 1: 27.3, 2: 26.8, 3: 26.5, 4: 26.0, 5: 25.7, 6: 25.4, 7: 24.6},
     ('date2', 'height'): {0: 8.7, 1: 9.3, 2: 10.8, 3: 12.7, 4: 13.5, 5: 17.8, 6: 18.9, 7: 20.0},
     ('date2', 'temp'): {0: 27.6, 1: 26.8, 2: 25.9, 3: 24.4, 4: 23.8, 5: 22.7, 6: 22.4, 7: 21.0},
     ('date3', 'height'): {0: 10.0, 1: 12.8, 2: 13.1, 3: 14.8, 4: 15.2, 5: 16.8, 6: 17.9, 7: 18.6},
     ('date3', 'temp'): {0: 26.0, 1: 25.5, 2: 25.3, 3: 24.7, 4: 24.3, 5: 23.7, 6: 23.3, 7: 23.0},
     ('date4', 'height'): {0: 9.5, 1: 10.8, 2: 11.4, 3: 12.9, 4: 13.6, 5: 14.0, 6: 14.7, 7: 15.9},
     ('date4', 'temp'): {0: 26.8, 1: 25.9, 2: 25.0, 3: 24.2, 4: 23.4, 5: 22.6, 6: 22.0, 7: 21.3}}
```

Then we need to reshape your data so that we have height and day as row/column names, and then temp as the values (a 2D array). Also, we convert the days to integers.

```
df = df.melt()
height_data = df[df.variable_1=='height'].reset_index(drop=True).copy()
temp_data = df[df.variable_1=='temp'].reset_index(drop=True).copy()
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': height_data.variable_0.str[4:].astype('int'), 
                   'height': height_data.value, 'temp': temp_data.value})
```

We pivot the dataframe in order to get the shape we want:

```
df = df.pivot('date', 'height').fillna(0)
X = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
Y = df.index.values
Z = df.values
Xi,Yi = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
plt.contour(Xi, Yi, Z, 20, cmap='RdGy')
```

Giving us this result:

[image]

Where x-axis is `day`, and y-axis is `height`, and the values are temperature - the result of `f(x,y)`, where x=day and y=temperature.

Comment: Thank you josh, but i am confused the way to generate my data from column to rows which your define by d={....}